# Retrieving data from HTML in RStudio

Tags: html, r, dataframe

I want to retrieve data frame from this HTML : https://www.transfermarkt.pl/pko-ekstraklasa/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/PL1/saison_id/2020/altersklasse/alle/detailpos//plus/1

Is there any simple way to get a table like from this site? I tried the way below, but I don't know what to enter in "html_node"

```
transfermarkt <- xml2::read_html("https://www.transfermarkt.pl/pko-ekstraklasa/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/PL1/saison_id/2020/altersklasse/alle/detailpos//plus/1")

transfermarkt %>%
  html_node("responsive-table") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: Have you tried the `rvest` package? Its site has some good guidance on scraping tables. https://rvest.tidyverse.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <kbd>Right click</kbd> on the table and choose `Inspect` to see the relevant selectors:

[image: element inspector]

1. Use `html_node("#yw1 table")` since you want the `<table>` inside `id="yw1"`
2. Change `html_text()` to `html_table()` since this is tabular data
3. Add `drop_na('#')` to remove superfluous rows (rows that have `NA` values in the `#` column)

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

transfermarkt <- xml2::read_html("https://www.transfermarkt.pl/pko-ekstraklasa/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/PL1/saison_id/2020/altersklasse/alle/detailpos//plus/1")

transfermarkt %>%
  html_node("#yw1 > table") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  drop_na('#')
```

| # | Zawodnik | Narodowość | Wiek (obecny) | Klub |  |  |  | Czas na boisku |  | Gole na mecz |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tomas Pekhart Środkowy napastnik | NA | Tomas Pekhart | Środkowy napastnik | NA | 31 |  | 19 | 0 | 5 | 1.510' | 79' | 1,00 |
| 2 | Jesús Imaz Ofensywny pomocnik | NA | Jesús Imaz | Ofensywny pomocnik | NA | 30 |  | 19 | 4 | 1 | 1.610' | 161' | 0,53 |
| 3 | Flávio Paixão Środkowy napastnik | NA | Flávio Paixão | Środkowy napastnik | NA | 36 |  | 22 | 3 | 4 | 1.693' | 188' | 0,41 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |